# Problems with counting upper and lower case in Python

Tags: python

Essentially, I am trying to read some text and count instances of letters. Very simple. However, no matter what I try, I get different results for `"E"` and `"e"`, when I want combined results. Here is what I have:

```
import nltk
import re

f = open('mytext.txt')
raw = f.read()
#print raw
#print len(raw) #7234

raw.lower()

prompt = raw_input("Enter stuff: ") 

potato = re.compile(r'[a-z]*', re.IGNORECASE)
potato = re.match(r'[a-z]*', prompt, re.IGNORECASE)
if potato: 
   print raw.count(prompt)
else:
   print "try again"

#document control f "e" = 808
#print result "e" = 802, "E" = 6
```

Comment: Try `raw = raw.lower()` rather than  just `raw.lower()`

Comment: Not sure if this matters, but if you are trying to convert raw to all lowercase, you have to save raw.lower() as a variable i.e. `raw_2 = raw.lower()` and then continue the rest of your code using raw_2 instead of raw

Comment: or do what @Kamehameha said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `raw.lower()` does nothing - you didn't store the result. Try this instead:

```
raw = raw.lower()
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
raw.lower()
```

does not do what you think it does. Replace it with

```
raw = raw.lower()
```

Python strings are immutable; any operation that you perform on them will return a *new* string with that modification.

If you want it to be case-insensitive for both the input text and the prompt entered by the user, also change

```
prompt = raw_input("Enter stuff: ")
```

to

```
prompt = raw_input("Enter stuff: ") 
prompt = prompt.lower()
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to make it so the user can search for "e" or "E" and get the same result?

Comment: (see my edit above...)